# How to read and write concurrently a pcap file in c

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap

I have 2 programs written in C, one program writes to the pcap file and the second program reads from it at the same time.For writing ,I am using the following code

```
while(j < 100000)
        {
            pcount = pcap_dispatch(p,2000,&pcap_dump,(u_char *)pd);
            j = j+pcount;
            printf("Got %d packets , total packets %d\n",pcount,j);
        }
```

And for decoding the packets, I am using the following code

```
while( (returnValue=pcap_next_ex(pcap,&header,&data)) >= 0)
        {
            printf("Packet # %d ",++packetCount);
            printf("return value %d\n",returnValue);
        }
```

When i run the program separately i.e when I stop writing to the pcap file, It decodes the packets perfectly. But when I run both the programs at the same time, the decoder does not decode all the packets. If i get 100 packets, the decoder will show only 50-60 decoded packets.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the ethernet speed? Where exactly is your program missing the packets? In the beginning, in the end or in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, reader's file is not getting updated as soon as the writer writes in the pcap file. This might be due to the reason that reader's file pointer is not refreshed i.e its reading the non updated version of file.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: you are right but how can i update the reader's file pointer to match that of writer's file pointer ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what pipes are for. I suggest something like

```
pcap_writer -w - | tee permanent-file.pcap | pcap_reader -r -
```

where `pcap_writer` and `pcap_reader` are your programs. This way you create something that can be combined in a different manner, if wanted.

Comment: Basically i have made the pcap file inside the writer program, so i cannot understand how i can pipe another pcap file because i am writing in my own pcap file (using my own sniffer) which is continuously being updated

Comment: Write to stdout instead of a file. Then you can pipe the output to a file with tee as well as send it to your reading program.